Unity Application.Persistentdatapath doesn't work in Android
//string path = @"C:\Users\yu\OneDrive\Desktop\Mak\Sumar\Assets\Jsons\LevelsJsons";
string path = Application.persistentDataPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar +"Jsons" +Path.DirectorySeparatorChar+ "LevelsJsons";

public void CreateJson(LevelModel model)
{
    string jsonPath = Path.Combine(path, (model.id.ToString() + ".json"));
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(model);
    File.WriteAllText(jsonPath, json);
    //AssetDatabase.Refresh();
}

public  LevelModel ReadJson(string fileName)
{
    string ReadedJson = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(path, (fileName + ".json")));
    LevelModel newJsonModel = JsonUtility.FromJson<LevelModel>(ReadedJson);
    return newJsonModel;
}

I can access Json files in Unity editor. I cannot access the path with Application.PersistentDataPath in Android. I cannot read Json files in Android. What am I missing?

just test it with $"{Application.persistentDataPath}\Jsons\LevelsJsons\{fileName}.json". in my experience Path.DirectorySeparatorChar and Path.Combine doesn't work as intended on android so I gave up on them :). test it in this way to see if persistentDataPath completely broken or there is a problem in path. if it works that way debug to see what is the path that you are passing to File.ReadAllText

$"{Application.persistentDataPath}\Jsons\LevelsJsons{fileName}.json" dont workıng  https://ibb.co/zNQbH2P

Have you tried Application.persistentDataPath + "/Jsons/LevelsJsons". Theoretically, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar should be "/", but I never did trust Windows when compiling. Try hardcoding the slash.

I tried this too. It didn't work. I can access it in unity editor, but I tried everything on android.

@TheNomad
My files are in the assets folder, such as assets/json/leveljson.
Do you think I should put it somewhere else? I'm stuck.

Wait, something is not clear. If you want to access the Assets directory, why are you using Application.persistentDataPath? What are you trying to actually do? If you need access to the assets location, why are you writing files inside it from code?

I just want to read and write json files. on android

first, I mistake back slash(\) and slash(/). second, persistent data path in window is C:\Users\<user>\AppData\LocalLow\<company name> and in android is /storage/emulated/<userid>/Android/data/<packagename>/files none of them is in asset folder. what do you mean it didn't work? do you get error on write? did you get empty content from read? what if you put a json file in that location? did you try printing the path to make sure you are looking in the correct location?

"I just want to read and write json files. on android". OK, but what is your use case. I mean, you don't do something just for the sake of doing it, there must be a reason, a workflow in your app or game, right?

To create path you can use:
Path.Combine(arg1, arg2, ...) //output: arg1/arg2/...

If you want to get json file, you can put inside Resources/ folder.
For example, json is located in Resouces/sample.json, you car read it like this:
TextAsset json = Resources.Load("sample") as TextAsset;
Debug.Log(json.text);


@AkhrcAkhrorjon I believe he wants to modify it and write it on disk at runtime (at least his code seems to indicate that). What you suggest won't work since Resources will be embedded in the build with the snapshot it had when deploying.

@TheNomad I need to reach the correct location
